# Sum a list which contains 'None' using Python

Tags: python, sum

Basically my question is say you have an list containing 'None' how would you try retrieving the sum of the list. Below is an example I tried which doesn't work and I get the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'`. Thanks

```
def sumImport(self):
    my_list = [[1,2,3,None],[1,2,3],[1,1],[1,1,2,2]]
    k = sum(chain.from_iterable(my_list))
    return k
```

Answer (score 73):

You can use `filter` function

```
>>> sum(filter(None, [1,2,3,None]))
6
```

**Updated from comments**

Typically `filter` usage is `filter(func, iterable)`, but passing `None` as first argument is a special case, described in [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter). Quoting:

> If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.

Comment: Maybe useful to mention for people who don't know (like me): *"If `function` is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of `iterable` that are false are removed."* ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter))

Comment: @FelixKling Updated my answer with doc link.

Comment: Notice every falsy element will be filtered : `list(filter(None, [0, 1, 2, None, False, True]))  # = [1, 2, True]`

Answer (score 14):

Remove `None` (and zero) elements before summing by using `filter`:

```
>>> k = sum(filter(None, chain.from_iterable(my_list)))
>>> k
20
```

To see why this works, see the [documentation for `filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

> `filter(function, iterable)`
>
> Construct a list from those elements of `iterable` for which `function` returns true. `iterable` may be either a sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If iterable is a string or a tuple, the result also has that type; otherwise it is always a list. If function is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.
>
> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]` if function is not `None` and `[item for item in iterable if item]` if function is `None`.

Comment: Cheers Mark this helped me out

Answer (score 7):

Another suggestion:

```
from itertools import chain
k = sum(x for x in chain.from_iterable(my_list) if x)
```

Comment: It would fail if you pass in the iterable some object which is "false" but nonetheless give some contribute to the sum. Using `if x is None` would solve this[even though I don't know why someone would create an object that results "false" but gives a contribute to a sum].

Comment: @Bakuriu: There doesn't exist *anything* that tests false but could contribute to a sum.

Comment: This would do that: `class MyClass(object): def __nonzero__(self):return False def __add__(self, other): return other + 1`. So there may exist something like this, even though no built-in type has this "property", and anyway creating such an object is probably not really useful.

Comment: Does this require importing something?  :  `NameError: name 'chain' is not defined`

Comment: @Mausy5043: Oops. Yes, actually: `from itertools import chain` is required. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to treat `None` as zero, a simple way is

```
sum(x if x is not None else 0 for x in chain.from_iterable(my_list))
```

Comment: You may as well drop the `None` values, since `0` is not going to contribute to the total sum either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This answer is helpful for those that want to add a value to each element in a list that may contain some `None` values.

Comment: @virtualxtc: yes, but the `if x is not None` test should go to the *end* of the loop, to filter out elements rather than add another `0` to the sum: `sum(x for x in chain.from_iterable(my_list) if x is not None)`. I didn't say the answer was not helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly, this is equivalent to filter:

```
k = sum([x for x in chain.from_iterable(my_list) if x])
```

That saves me from remembering another function.  :P

Answer (score 1):

You always have the option of just writing the loop you want:

```
k = 0
for sublist in my_list:
    for val in sublist:
        if val is not None:
            k += val
```

But it certainly doesn’t hurt to know about `filter` either.

Answer (score 0):

Just using sum and map:

```py
sum(map(lambda x: x or 0, [1,2,3,None])) 
# 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In case one's intention is to sum up the numbers only, one can also do type checking. For example:

```
test_list = [2,4,6,8.9,9.0,None,False,True,'abc','vv']
sum([x for x in test_list if type(x) is float or type(x) is int])
```