# Why it says NaN when I'm trying to sum rows using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
Title Netquantity Bases Chambers
x          2              4
y                 5
```

To get the total of bases chambers, I've used

```
concat_list.loc['Total'] = concat_list[['Bases','Chambers']].sum()
```

However, the output was

```
Title Netquantity Bases Chambers

x          2              4
y                 5        
Total    NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Could you help me to debug this issue? Some of the numbers are empty. I tried to

```
concat_list = concat_list.fillna(0)
```

But still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is problem there are values mixed strings with numeric or all strings, first tray convert to `floats`:

```
concat_list.loc['Total'] = concat_list[['Bases','Chambers']].astype(float).sum()
```

If not working, try replace not parseable values to missing values by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) per all columns, so use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
concat_list.loc['Total'] = concat_list[['Bases','Chambers']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum()
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate question of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229902/sum-a-list-which-contains-none-using-python

Comment: @Hamed_gibago - I think not.

Comment: @jazrael still not working. The first solution didnt work. Output was  ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
But the second one worked. Could you explain the line .apply briefly?

Comment: @SamuelSaerang - Second solution working?

Comment: @jezrael it's working could you explain briefly the .apply logic?